# ReactJS with useRef: focusing a toggle-able form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working with React functional components.

I have a `<form>` element that I want to be toggle-able between `display: none` and being displayed, and to `focus()` on its main `<input>` when it appears.

(I'm using react-hook-form to handle the submission of the form, which I don't think impacts the question, but explains some of the lines of code that might not be clear at first.)

```
const EditBox = (props) => {
    const [mebOpen, setMebOpen] = useState(false);
    const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();
    const field = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log(field.current);
        if (mebOpen) {
            field.current.focus();
        }
    }, [mebOpen]);

    return (
        <>
            <span
                className={`clickable`}
                onClick={() => setMebOpen(!mebOpen)}
            >
                {props.triggerText}
            </span>
            <form
                className={`popout ${mebOpen ? "open" : "closed"}`}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleVal)}
            >
                <input
                    ref={field}
                    type={props.inputType}
                    {...register("newVal")}
                />
                <button type="submit">Enter</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}
```

Relevant CSS:

```
> form.popout.closed {
    display: none;
}
> form.popout.open {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2.6rem;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

With the above code, the toggling of the form's appearance works, but I get an error saying that `field.current` is `null` and its property `focus()` can't be found. I.e. the `ref={field}` code doesn't go off until AFTER the `useEffect` hook fires.

I tried setting a second `useState` variable, just a simple counter, to chain-react two `useEffect` hooks; it was inelegant but I thought it might be the way to force `focus()` to run after the `<input>` renders. But the chain-reacted render re-set the `<input>` element too, so it still never focused.

How can I get this to work? Would learning about `forwardRef` help?

Comment: Did you tried using autofocus attribute? It should come to focus when visible

Comment: I did try that, it didn't work either. Not sure why.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the **{...register("newVal")}** 
I created [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ogbivh?file=node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/useForm.d.ts) and if you remove that part, the focus start working.

Comment: You're right Thremulant, commenting out that line makes the focus() work somehow. Guess I need to find how react-hook-form handles refs or focusing. Want to write your comment as an Answer so I can mark it the correct answer?

Comment: Fixed it in the stackblitz and posted the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](https://www.react-hook-form.com/faqs/) from react-hook-form FAQs:

> **How to share ref usage?**
> React Hook Form needs a ref to collect the input value, however, you may want to use ref for other purposes (e.g. scroll into the view, or focus).

And this are the parts you're missing:

1. Add a new hook using **register**

```
  const { ref, ...rest } = register('newVal');
```

2. Modify your input:

```
 <input
   {...rest}
   ref={e => {
     ref(e);
     field.current = e;
   }}
 />
```

Check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ogbivh?file=src/EditBox.js) I've made with your code.
PD: I modified the CSS, just to see the form.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found this FAQ in the interim, but your work still helped me adapt it.